# Decrease div height relative to its' original

Tags: html, css

How can I decrease the height of the div in relation to the height it would have been rendered natively?

Seems like a rather simple question but setting height to a percentage isn't an option, neither is `margin: 0 -10px 0 0;` or `padding: 0 -10px 0 0;` (obviously) there aren't any elements within the div I can decrease the size of, if I apply the margin it seems to work except border-radius is hurt from this process.

Comment: some code please? jsfiddle?

Comment: jQuery seems like the best option for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
$('div').animate({'height':'-=10px'}, 1000);
```

the "-=10px" will decrease the current height by 10px.